# How to reset ModelState values?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am checking a model for validity in an action. The repository throws various exceptions depending on how the checks I carry out go, so the action contains a try-catch statement.

```
[AcceptVerb(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult MyAction1(Action1Model Model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
        try
        {
             new MyModelRepository().CarryOutSomeChecks(Model);
             return View("SuccessfulView")
        }
        catch (ValidationException)
        {
             Model.Result = Result.Fail;
             ModelState.... <= I would like to reset the ModelState here.
        }
    return View(Model)
}
```

The view model contains some sensitive information, so if the checks fail I would like to return to the view and remove the values which were input by the user.

To complicate things in my view I call actually has two partial views in it that show a form each, so like:

```
@model MyProject.MyOverallViewModel
@{
}

@{Html.RenderPartial("MyAction1Form", Model.Action1ModelInstance);}
@{Html.RenderPartial("MyAction2Form", Model.Action2ModelInstance);}
```

I have tried doing Model = new Model() in the catch, but, even though the model passed to the view is all null, the values entered to the form are persisted. I assume this is because of ModelState... Is there a way to reset that?

I would like to avoid doing a RedirectToAction so that I can persist the result of my check within my model when the view is displayed again.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`ModelState.Clear();` should do the job.

Comment: Yes, you're right, it did. Strange, I tried that about half an hour ago and the values were persisted... Must be getting tired. Thanks!

Comment: Just to clarify, ModelState.Clear() works, but only if I then also go through the model and reset all the properties. Kinda makes sense thinking about it now...

Comment: @user643192, instead of going through your model and resetting its properties one by one you could simply `return View(new Action1Model());` just after resetting your modelstate.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was doing when I said I was resetting all properties.